# Get total size of collections in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

Is there a quick method to estimate the size of collections in bytes?
The System admin needs to know the storage size for data export. What I have in the code returns the number of fragments. I appreciate any help you can provide.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $collection := "/citation/TRWA"
let $total-size := xdmp:estimate(cts:search(collection($collection),cts:true-query()))
return $total-size
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extrapolate and estimate size by sampling some of the documents and multiplying the count of docs in the collection by an average of those sampled docs.

For a fast and accurate answer, you would need to compute the size and have it in an indexed field (either range-indexed element/field/property or TDE column).

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what kind of export you had in mind. A database backup is the simplest approach. The size is similar to the disk size footprint of the normal database.

An MLCP export is another approach, but you have 3 types:

- export of separate files in a folder structure. You can use the sampling approach described by Mats to get an estimate
- compressed export of the files as zips. Size is similar to the separate files, but typically 30% less.
- archive (compressed) export. Contains the same as compressed export, but with
  sidecar documents that capture the meta information of each document.

And you could probably use Corb2 to generate CSV data to capture the contents, rather than the files.

HTH!